# How to put both a key and its value from a dictionary through a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, key-value

I'm curious as to how I can put both a key and its value from a dictionary through a function.
The following code is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
dictionary: {
    'apple': 1,
    'pear': 2,
    'strawberry': 3
}

def my_function(fruit, num):
    print(fruit)
    print(num)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Do you know how to call a function? How to access a value from a dictionary?

Comment: Your function isn't clear: it takes both the key and value as an argument, before printing them both. I don't imagine that's what you want to do...

Comment: @JaredWilber - Why not? Its common to process key/value pairs. It could be just to print, it could be that this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function prints information about key/value pairs. `dict.items` iterates key/value pairs. 
Looks like a great match.

```
dictionary = {
    'apple': 1,
    'pear': 2,
    'strawberry': 3
}

def my_function(fruit, num):
    print(fruit)
    print(num)

for fruit, num in dictionary.items():
    my_function(fruit, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one mistake in your code, you should use `=` instead of `:` for assigning dictionary.

You can just pass the `dictionary` to the function:

```py
dictionary = {
    'apple': 1,
    'pear': 2,
    'strawberry': 3
}

def my_function(key, value):
    print(key, value)

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    my_function(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.keys()`:

```
dictionary = {
    'apple': 1,
    'pear': 2,
    'strawberry': 3
}

def my_function(fruit, num):
    print(fruit,end=' ')
    print(num)

for fruit in dictionary.keys():
    my_function(fruit, dictionary[fruit])
```

Output:

```
apple 1
pear 2
strawberry 3
```

Answer (score 0):

At first , i would like to draw your attention that you mistakenly use `':'` instead of `'='`  while adding keys-values in dictionary. **(FIRST LINE)**

Now , lets come to the point , there are several ways to solve it such as `dict.items()` as follows:

## Method 1st :

```
def myDict(dict):
    for fruit , num in dict.items(): #dict.item(), returns keys & val to Fruit& num 
    print(fruit+" : "+str(num))   # str(num) is used to concatenate string to string.


dict = {'apple':1,'pear':2,'strawberry':3}         
res = myDict(dict)
print(res)                              *#result showing*

**OUTPUT :**

apple : 1 
pear : 2 
strawberry : 3
```

**METHOD : 2**

```
dictionary = {
    'apple': 1,
    'pear': 2,
    'strawberry': 3 }

def MyDict(key,value):
   print (key+" : "+str(value))   # str(num) is used to concatenate string to string.

for fruits , nums in dictionary.items():
    MyDict(fruits,nums)                   # calling function in a loop

    OUTPUT :
    apple : 1
    pear : 2
    strawberry : 3
```

I hope , this will assist you ..
**Thankyou**